# @JsonUnwrapped for Custom Serializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a relatively complex object which contains a number of fields.  I need to serialize one of the fields using a custom serializer, but need to emulate the `@JsonUnwrapped` functionality.

For simplicity's sake I'll cut this down to two fields:

```
public class MyClass
{
  @JsonProperty("subject")
  private final String subject;
  @JsonSerialize(using=MySenderSerializer.class)
  private final MailActor sender;
}
```

and my custom serializer class is as follows:

```
public class MySenderSerializer extends StdSerializer<MailActor>
{
  public MySenderSerializer()
  {
    super(MailActor.class, true);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(final MailActor value, final JsonGenerator gen, final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException
  {
    gen.writeStringField("from_name", value.getName());
    gen.writeStringField("from_email", value.getAddress());
  }
}
```

All of this is fine, except that the output JSON looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "subject": "test subject",
  "sender": {
    "from_name": "test from",
    "from_email": "test@test.com"
  },
  ...
}
```

and I need to unwrap the `sender` field so that the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "subject": "test subject",
  "from_name": "test from",
  "from_email": "test@test.com",
  ...
}
```

If I was using standard serializers I could use the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation to do this, but it doesn't appear to be compatible with custom serializers.  How can I obtain the required JSON output without writing a custom serializer for the `MyClass` object?

Answer (score 2):

I have had to look for an alternative to *@JsonUnwrapped* too, as it was causing me some unrelated issues with this question.

The solution I have implemented would apply to your case similarly, using *@JsonAnyGetter*. In your MyClass ignore the attribute that needs the special serialization and instead add it with the *JsonAnyGetter*:

```
public class MyClass
{
    @JsonProperty("subject")
    private final String subject;
    @JsonIgnore
    private final MailActor sender;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> serializeActor() {
         return sender.serializeToMap();
         // Of course, here you could create an empty map
         // and add the properties of many different classes.
    }
}
```

Then in the MailActor class you implement that method which will return a map with the properties that you may want.

```
public Map<String, Object> serializeToMap() {
    final Map<String, Object> properties = new ArrayMap<>();
    properties.put("from_name", this.getName());
    properties.put("from_email", this.getAddress());
    return properties;
}
```

The problem of going this way is deserializing the object, since the @JsonAnySetter doesn't get the map with the JSON in a map the same way you give it with the example above. In your case it's even more difficult, as your class' attributes are final. You'd need to use a @JsonCreator which would have to create all your attributes. Something along the lines of:

```
@JsonCreator
public MyClass( Map< String, String > json ) {
    if (json.containsKey("subject")) {
        subject = json.get("subject");
    } else {
        subject = "";
    }

    String name, address;
    if (json.containsKey("from_name")) {
        name = json.get("from_name");
    } else {
        name = "";
    }
    if (json.containsKey("from_email")) {
        address = json.get("from_email");
    } else {
        address = "";
    }
    sender = new MailActor(name, address);
}
```

It's been a while since you posted the question, hopefully this is helpful in some way to someone coming to look for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is because you have designed it to be that way, when jackson maps an object it will map the inner properties as sub-properties of that object, if you want it to serialize those two fields as if they were members of MyClass instead of MailActor, then declare them as such.

This may point out that your object design may have some small flaws.

I would write a custome serializer for the MyClass object but still, in the long run is not a viable solution.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the object design has flaws; it works fine in other areas, including other calls in the same API, and the issue is fitting it to the expected format for a particular call in a particular API.

Comment: Then it should be a different object, i suppose. Because you dont want an object Mail with a Sender object inside, you want a Mail object with sender properties unwrapped, i dont really see it as a json parsing problem that is what i mean by object design.

Comment: Thanks for the continued response but my struggle is with Jackson not the object model.  The same information (name and email address) shows up in different parts of the API in different formats: sometimes wrapped and sometimes not, and with different field names.  Whatever I choose as my object design I will have this issue, and it's an issue which is usually tackled in Jackson with `@JsonUnwrapped` but that doesn't play nicely with custom serializers.  Hence the question if there is something equivalent I can do with the custom serializer.